# How to clean up the resulted csv file and html file in nonGUI mode using Jmeter command

Tags: jmeter

I have created a testsuite in JMETER and running through nonGUI mode and capturing the results in csv file and using same csv file data and generating a dashboard report.
Since i wanted to do continuous integration, need to clean up the result files each time and regenerate fresh result data files.

Comment: What do you use for CI?

Comment: Stash, Electric commander

Comment: I don't know how that works, but could you just clean up (delete) files before you run the actual test?

Comment: ya i can do that manually, after doing manual cleanup i am able to run the actual test and its generating reports. But i wanted to do clean up using jmeter commands in command line.

Comment: @Ivan Markovic, Please go thru one more question i posted, How to create folder with unique name while running a Jmeter command in nonGUI mode

Comment: You can create Beanshell/Groovy script to delete old data. Just put it in SetUp Thread Group. It will run before actual test.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute JMeter with `-f` option which delete existing results files:

> -f, --forceDeleteResultFile
>           force delete existing results files before start the test

See [full options list](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options).